# Calling Multiple Factories and Combining Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an angular 1.4 application and had a question around where to combine data. I have 2 factories which each have functions and I need to call one factory (factory 1) which calls an API to get some data and then use that data to call another factory (factory 2) function which calls an API to retrieve additional data. I am wondering should I be creating a new factory or service to call factory 1 and then factory 2? Or is this something that should be done in the controller?

Comment: You can use `$injector` to manually retrieve a singleton service/factory, check the official api: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector . Using this, you can get the singleton instance of the second factory and use it in the first one. Example: `var _myFactory2 = $injector.get('factory2name');`

Answer (score 0):

Controller is not responsible for gathering data, so you shouldn't create complicated http calls in your `controller`. It's recommended to create an other method in your service/factory or create an other service/factory at all (based on your business logic) which returns a promise with the data which were collected from two separate http calls.